# l-Diversity logarithm

Tags: entropy, anonymity

I wanted to make a little example for anonymization evaluation using l-Diversity. For that I'm using the following formula for Entropy l-Diversity ($E$ is the equivalence class, $S$ are all possible values for a sensitive attribute, $s$ a specific value):

$$
        \operatorname{Entropy}(E) = - \sum_{s \in S} p(E,s)\cdot \log(p(E,s))
$$

In the [paper](http://www.cse.psu.edu/%7Eduk17/papers/ldiversityTKDDdraft.pdf) they never defined which logarithm is used. It could be base $2$, $e$ or $10$, but I have no Idea what is actually used. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entropy and other measures of information can be defined to any base and so should always be quoted with units ([bits/shannons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon_(unit)) for base 2, [nats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nat_(unit)) for base e, and [bans/harts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartley_(unit)) for base 10). The most common base is base 2, but this is by no means universal

Comment: The problem is, that the result should be a standardised score. I saw, that there is one single part used for proof in the appendix, where they evaluated some values. This leads to logarithm naturalis, therefore base $e$.

Comment: @Titanlord Yet in cryptography, it's almost universally base 2. That leads to bits.